# How allow folder permission for another user in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

Consider two user accounts `user1` and `user2` on one Linux machine. I want `user2` to be able to have read and write access to a folder in `user1` home directory.

So far created a group for both users and added both users

```
groupadd twousers
usermod -a -G twousers user1
usermod -a -G twousers user2
```

then changed the group and the path and changed the permission

```
chgrp twousers /home/user1/folder
chmod g+rwx /home/user1/folder
```

Unfortunately `user2` is still unable to access the folder `/home/user1/folder`. It seems to be quite simple but somehow I am lost. What am I missing?

Comment: alright. the posted it in the linux network. how do I delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

```
chown user1.twousers /home/user1/folder

chmod 775 /home/user1/folder
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this until you get the permission and make sure you don't mess up the path or name of the file or folder:

```
chmod u+rwX,g+rwX,o+rwX
```